# How to send SOAP requests in ISO-8859-1 with Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, soap, encoding, character-encoding

Flex uses by default UTF-8. I have not fount a way to specify a different encoding/charset on the actionscript WebService class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ummm, look here:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/struts_06.html

I think that sample implies that declaring your mxml file as iso-8859-1 might do the trick, but I really don't think so.

I might be wrong but as far as I know the Flash player only handles UTF-8 encoding. I've searched for a link to an official page saying so, but couldn't find it.

If that's the case you either:

a) update the webservice to handle UTF-8 encoding

b) if that's not possible, proxy your call to your own webservice that accepts UTF-8 and then call the actual one.

You might want to give a go to the old system.useCodepage=true trick BUT that didn't use to work when the user was on Linux or Mac, USE WITH CARE!

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way to specify an encoding to the flex compiler but that does not seem to work.
Right now the only solution I have found is to re-encode the incomming requests on the server side.
I am surprised this limitation is not written black on white in the flex reference documentation.